# How do I bring a window to the front, without "switching" apps in electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

So for example lets say the user has Chrome open in full screen. Then a popup comes from the electron app, but it overlays on the chrome screen instead of switching screens to the electron app.

Like the VPN app below;[image]

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Your question is a statement. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 6):

To focus a window, you can use: `window.show()`.

If your on a mac and it's in a different workspace then it won't show. You would need to run: `window.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true)` on the window when the window is being created then `window.show()` when you want it to show.

[`show` docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winshow)

[`setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces` docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetvisibleonallworkspacesvisible)

Comment: tttthhhaaankkks

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that seems to work for this! So this is assuming you've already figured out how to show a window above full screen apps in general. The issue I had with that is that when you try to bring a new window into view, it takes you out of fullscreen, even if that window is configured to show above fullscreen apps.

To deal with this the solution was simple:

```
mainWindow.hide()
mainWindow.show()

setTimeout(() => displayPopupWindow(data), 300)
```

In this case, your main window (which can be invisible) is given focus while still having the fullscreen app open, then opening the popup window *will not* close the fullscreen app.